# Qt: script runs before button is pressed

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

I have created a gui that has two buttons: one that says "Open Input File:" and one that says "Run".

When someone clicks on "Open Input File:", he/she can select a file as input, and when that person then clicks on "Run", the script runScrapy is supposed to start.

The part where the buttons are set looks like this:

```
def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
    self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open Input File:"))
    self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.showDialog)
    self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Run"))
    self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.runScrapy)
    self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Happy Scraping"))

def showDialog(self):
    fileName = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()
    if fileName:
        global file
        file = fileName[0]
        print(file)

def runScrapy(self):
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(BasicSpider)
    process.start()  # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
```

However, instead of running "runScrapy" when pushButton_2 is clicked, "runScrapy" starts running immediately after I start this script. I don't understand why, since showDialog does only pop up after you've clicked "Open Input File:".

**Q:** How do I change my code so that runScrapy only runs when pushButton_2 is clicked?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start with Qt event handling.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
# set your window/mainwindow here
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Maybe this tutorial is also helpful: [Qt GUI app with python](http://pythonforengineers.com/your-first-gui-app-with-python-and-pyqt/)